# What is the difference between Google Identity Toolkit, Google OAuth, Firebase Auth and Google+ sign in

Tags: oauth, firebase-authentication, google-plus, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

For my understanding, Google Identity Toolkit provides a layer for login with different accounts, like Facebook, Yahoo etc. but how does that differ from the Google OAuth implementation? And regarding Google+ sign in, it is still using OAuth, but only enables login for Google accounts?

Comment: I agree that Google has not described this very well. And I would like a clear answer to. I think that Google Identity Toolkit is build with the single purpose to authenticate users and Google+ Sign In purpose is mostly to integrate the Google+ platform into your app, e.g. posts, likes, friends etc. So if your only need is to authenticate users, then go with Google Identity Toolkit. However I was also a bit confused about the Google+ Sign In since it allows users to create accounts and sign in with just username and password.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update as of December 28, 2018**:
Google is pushing a new service called [Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-cp/docs/).
Which is basically Firebase Authentication just for all GCP customers.

This service offers, like Firebase Authentication, an abstraction layer to any authentication platform (with easy 2-factor authentication starting at GA)

Google Sign-In and Smart Lock are both only the underlying "low level" technologies used by the Firebase Authentication and Cloud Identity Platform client SDKs.

**Update as of June 15, 2016**: It seems the guide mentioned in the original answer (below) is not kept up to date - the [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/) seems to be on its way out, apparently absorbed into the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), which is not even mentioned in that guide.

Maybe a better starting point for checking the **current** Google authentication solutions *might be* the "**Sign In + Identity**" icon on the [Products](https://developers.google.com/products/) page.

**Original answer**:

I recently saw this Google Identity Platform guide for choosing between various Google identity solutions which may answer some/all of your questions:
https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth
[image]

Comment: Identity platform is very expensive, whereas Identity Toolkit was free. Are there any cheaper alternatives now that identity toolkit is gone?

Comment: @Price [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/) - in which the identity toolkit was absorbed, appears to be free...

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yes, but you have to sign up for the Firebase pay-as-you-go plan and even then some of the [email limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits) for things like email verification / password reset are quite low. The Identity Toolkit page doesn't say it's being deprecated - is sticking with it an option?

Comment: Sorry, just realized that while Id. Toolkit is [not currently planned to be deprecated](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/migrate-firebase), it is not free - it has same pricing as Identity Platform according to the API console.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Can you please answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391084/firebase-authentication-vs-google-identity-toolkit-pricing

Comment: @Ayyappa I can't really, I have yet to try out Firebase.