# How to do facebook login with GAE Python endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new to GAE Python, I want to give user option to login with facebook. I am already being able to add SignIn with Google. How I can implement facebook login ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer to this question points to a Google auth solutions choosing guide: [What is the difference between Google identity toolkit, Google OAauth and Google+ sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442786/what-is-the-difference-between-google-identity-toolkit-google-oaauth-and-google/31053422#31053422)

Answer (score 1):

I think that [simpleauth](https://simpleauth.appspot.com/) for appengine can be what you need. I use it myself and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Facebook signin, please refer to [Configure Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/configure-service) and search for "Configure Facebook login".