# Custom Authentication for Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I'm developing an android application and i've been stuck in this for a few days. OAUTH 2.0 + google accounts is great and all that, but i do not want to tightly couple my application to work only with google accounts.

How do I implement custom authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This Q&A has a pointer to Google Identity Platform guide for choosing between various Google identity solutions: [What is the difference between Google identity toolkit, Google OAauth and Google+ sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442786/what-is-the-difference-between-google-identity-toolkit-google-oaauth-and-google/31053422#31053422)