# Google App Engine Golang - Register Users Without Google Account

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, go

I'm building a website in Go(lang) using Google App Engine. I want users to be able to register for the site by providing an Email and Password. I don't want to use the users API, because I don't want my users to require a google account and I eventually plan on making this a pay site.

What is a good way to handle user registration/authentication on google app engine? Should I use the datastore for user accounts and credentials, or Cloud SQL? Any other good options? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO it's easier to use an existing, reputable infrastructure/service.
Google offers such services, see [What is the difference between Google identity toolkit, Google OAauth and Google+ sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442786/what-is-the-difference-between-google-identity-toolkit-google-oaauth-and-google/31053422#31053422).

I opted for the [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/), which nicely supports simultaneously both private accounts and federated logins with several popular identity providers.

**Update June 17, 2016**: The banner on the GITkit doumentation authentication indicates GITkit may be on its way out, to be absorbed into the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

Comment: That's really interesting and something I hadn't come across before. Definitely going to check it out.