# Store app settings on a cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

For my android app, I would like to store some app user files in a cloud. The user shall be able to upload any content created before to a cloud, by easy logging in with any valid account facebook, twitter, openID account, etc.

I realized that already with a OpenId Connect example. What cloud possibilites do I have? I think Google offers something appropiate?

Comment: how you validate a user is unrelated to where you store the files.

Comment: The title makes it sound like you want to store user settings/metadata but the body of your question makes it sound like you want to store actual user files. Is it both?

Comment: Yes both. When user has new smartphone, he shall not configure much. user shall just login and be able to access its app settings/metadata and its precaptured user data.

Answer (score 0):

Answering from the [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) prospective only, assuming you're willing to write a GAE app. Other options are likely available as well, but I opted for GAE.

A variety of [storage options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/#storage) are available to store your user data, some may be more appropriate than others depending on the type of data and your preferences. Comparison between storage options available [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/storing-your-data).

A variety of user authentication methods are available, some may be more appropriate than others depending on you app requirements and your preferences, see: [What is the difference between Google identity toolkit, Google OAauth and Google+ sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442786/what-is-the-difference-between-google-identity-toolkit-google-oaauth-and-google/31053422#31053422)