# Validate google apps user's username and password

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-api, single-sign-on

I want to validate google apps user's username and password for custom login page(SSO Login) using SAML Protocol.

Options I tried:

1) Google [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin) library which is working till April 20, 2015 but after that it was deprecated.

2) Android play services authentication using this url:
    https://android.clients.google.com/auth. More detailed [article](http://sbktech.blogspot.in/2014/01/inside-android-play-services-magic.html)

3) Connect using SMTP. Code snippet extracted from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python):

```
    username = 'emailsmtplibtest@gmail.com'
    password = 'passtest'   
    from_addr = 'emailsmtplibtest@gmail.com'    
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
```

But its not promising as user can disable "Access for less secure apps" which will fail when we use SMTP.

Is there any other way or API to validate google apps user's username and password ?

Comment: This *might* help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442786/what-is-the-difference-between-google-identity-toolkit-google-oaauth-and-google/31053422#31053422

Comment: What do you mean validate?  You want the user to give you their google password?  I certainly would uninstall an app that asked for that.  You shouldn't need to know the user's password - what is the larger goal here?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks for your reply but not find any relevant content which will validate username and password.

Comment: @nasch This is how single sign on SAML works

Comment: @Kartik My mistake.  Sagar, what is the problem with option 2?

Comment: @nasch with option 2 if user is administrator of google apps with wrong password got response "Error=BadAuthentication" and  with right password got response "Error=BadAuthentication Info=WebLoginRequired" or some token response but user is not administrator of google apps then it will be always got response "Error=BadAuthentication Info=WebLoginRequired"

Comment: This is how SAML *can* work but it is definitely not recommend practice to ask users for their passwords to other services.